# QX11EmbedContainer alternative in Qt5

Tags: qt, embed, qt5.6, qx11embedcontainer

I need `QX11EmbedContainer`, but in new version of Qt 5.6 it dissapeared.

Is there another alternative to `QX11EmbedContainer` that works/exists in Qt 5.6?

Comment: Yes, all QX11EmbedContainer stuff was excluded from Qt 5. Have you got already any existing code which we can look at or could you explain what would you like to do with QX11EmbedContainer?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`QWidget::createWindowContainer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer) and [`QWindow::fromWinId`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#fromWinId).  I think those should get you what you want.

Comment: It works correctly, thanks you very muchas.

Answer (score 0):

This is the comment from @g-m copied as a proper answer:

> You might want to take a look at [`QWidget::createWindowContainer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer) and [`QWindow::fromWinId`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#fromWinId). I think those should get you what you want.